# Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type

Tags: c#, generics

There is a base class which has one method of generic type and I am sure that in my derived I will be returning a string. This is my code:

```
public abstract class Base
    {
        public virtual T GetSomething<T>()
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public class Extended : Base
    {
        public override string GetSomething<string>()
        {
            return string.Empty;

            //return base.GetSomething<T>();
        }
    }
```

But this code doesn't compile. Can anybody spot the mistake? I am sure that in my Extended class I want to return string only. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot override a generic method with a concrete implementation; that's not how generics work.  The `Extended` class must be able to handle calls to `GetSomething<int>()` for example.

In other words, the signature for an overriding method must be *identical* to the method it is overriding.  By specifying a concrete generic implementation of the method, you change its signature.

Consider using this approach:

```
public override T GetSomething<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return string.Empty;

    return base.GetSomething<T>();
}
```

Note that the JIT should optimize away the conditional when compiling a particular instantiation of this method.  (If it doesn't then it's not a very good JIT!)

(The syntax for your override is technically correct, but fails for other reasons as well.  For example, you can't use the keyword `string` as a generic parameter name.  And if you could, your code still wouldn't do what you want, nor would it compile, since the compiler would be unable to find a method with that signature on a supertype.)

Comment: or change the base class declaration to `public abstract class Base<T>`

Comment: Perhaps, and then `Extended : Base<string>`.  That's certainly possible.  It's not immediately clear what the OP is trying to accomplish, so I chose the approach that requires minimal change to the class design.